# Is it possible to hide Force Push actions in a pull request on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Recently, GitHub made it so that force pushes are displayed in the pull request change history. I like to rebase my branches often (every couple hundred commits) to avoid compatibility issues, so now all of my pull requests look like this:

[image]

This is just clutter, is there any way that I can hide this? If not, where can I submit a feature request to GitHub.com itself to get these force push notifications to optionally go away?

Comment: This is recorded [here](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-11-15-force-push-timeline-event/). It seems you can contact them with twitter. However, I don't understand why github decided to do so.

Comment: that isn't github exclusive, other collaborative version control tools such as Bitbucket also have the same behavior

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to hide them, all my pull requests are now a mess of force pushes too.

Answer (score -5):

I know this is an old thread but maybe it will help others.

You can clean-up these commits with Git Squash. See https://pushbuildtestdeploy.com/hide-your-shameful-commits-with-git-squash/ for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, squashing commits does nothing to remove previous head-change events in GitHub issues/PRs.

Comment: Once you squash the commits, you have to force-push, which displays a new force-push in the PR. This answer you posted is what causes the exact problem I mentioned in the OP.